# preg_match_all php match # symbol failed

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php

$url = 'www.google.com/#123_abc';
preg_match_all ('/(\/#.*)/', $url, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Something is wrong with my regex? I get nothing for $result.

Comment: Where does `>` from your regex matches the string ?

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry that was a typo

Comment: what are you trying to match? `#123_abc` ?

Comment: This code of Yours works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be:

```
$url = 'www.google.com/#123_abc';
preg_match_all ('~(/#.*)~', $url, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

You have an extra `>` at the end of your regex making your `preg_match_all` function fail. Also better to use an alternate regex delimiter `~` to avoid escaping `/`.

Comment: why I can't do echo `$result[1];` ?

Comment: @AaronMusktin you can..

Comment: it says array to string conversiton. I thought $result[1] already trying to access the array?

Comment: @AaronMusktin: You can do: `$result[0][1]`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `>` in your regex.. remove it.. i.e:

```
preg_match_all ('/(\/#.*)/', $url, $result);
```